# How to get name initials in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a way in `SQLite` to get the first letter of each word in a string? For example:

Name:

> John Jonah Johnson

Query:

```
SELECT (get the initials from Name) as initials FROM Persons
```

Result:

> JJJ

I've found several examples for MySQL and SQL Server, but none for SQLite so far.

EDIT:

Example for SQL Server

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Frank Thomas',1,1) + '.' +
SUBSTRING('Frank Thomas',CHARINDEX(' ','Frank Thomas')+1,1) + '.' AS Initials;

Initials
F.T.
```

Example for MySQL

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('Frank Thomas',1,1), '.', SUBSTRING('Frank Thomas
',LOCATE(' ','Frank Thomas')+1,1), '.') AS Initials;
+----------+
| Initials |
+----------+
| F.T.     |
+----------+
```

These examples come from [here](http://www.erikhaselhofer.com/?p=3856).

EDIT2:

Currently I made the following:

```
 select (substr(Name,1,1) || '.' || 
 substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1,1) || '.' || 
 substr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),instr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),' ')+1,1) || '.')
 as Initials from Persons;
```

But this always shows 3 initials even if there is only one name in Name. Is there a more dynamic way to do this in SQLite?

Comment: If you know the maximum number of initials, say three, and you know there is always one blank between the names, you can take the first letter, then the one after the first blank, then the one after the second blank... Simply a combination of string functions.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I've done what you suggested, but there is no set amount of initials, the amount can vary. I've added the query of that test above as "EDIT2".

Comment: There must be some limit. Would you accept a name with 100 initials? Certainly not. So where do you set that Limit? At four initials maybe? You can use `CASE WHEN` and `LIKE` in order to check whether there are, say, three blanks in the name: `case when name like '% % % %' then ...`. If you don't want to set a limit, you'll have to write a recursive query.

Comment: Such a task is much easier solved with a programming language by the way.

Comment: It would be possible to write a recursive common table expression, but that would be rather complex.

Answer (score -1):

I've got a working query that supports upto 4 initials, but this is messy, is there really no simpler, more dynamic way to do this?

```
 select (substr(Name,1,1) || '.'
 || (case when (length(Name) - length(replace(Name, ' ', '')) + 1) > 1 then substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1,1) || '.'
 || (case when (length(Name) - length(replace(Name, ' ', '')) + 1) > 2 then substr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),instr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),' ')+1,1) || '.'
 || (case when (length(Name) - length(replace(Name, ' ', '')) + 1) > 3 then substr(substr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),instr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),' ')+1),(instr(substr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),instr(substr(Name,instr(Name,' ')+1),' ')+1),' ')+1),1) || '.'
 else '' end) else '' end) else '' end)) as Initials from Persons;
```

Comment: Yes - don't use SQL for this. It's a relational query language after all, and rather weak on conditional branching, thus making it hard to handle exceptions and special cases.